# Renaming multiple images files while uploading to MySQL database with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How are you developers.

I am trying implement a multiple images upload system on my website.

I want to know how to rename multiple images and store their path names into MySQL database using php. But if possible some JavaScript can be added.

I have searched through the net but I have found no working answer.
Please help me..... Below is the code.

I am try to avoid images existing files being overwritten in case someone uploads images of the name that are already in the directory.

Comment: Are you looking for [`move_uplaoded_file()`](https://php.net/move_uploaded_file)?

Comment: No but rename files while uploading.

Comment: "While uploading" - in transit - there is no filename. It's just bytes and you can store them anywhere you want.

Comment: I am trying to implement a multiple image upload feature on the website, but I want the files to berename d using timestamp before they are uploaded.

Comment: You can't rename files before upload. You can't change the name of the file on the clients computer lol

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, But what I also mean is, before they are uploaded using move_uploaded_function(); I want their bae changed to something else not their original name.

Comment: Simply use a different name when u save the file after upload. What is the actual problem ?

Comment: I am able to upload the images with their original name for the source. So I want to avoid images to be duplicated or overwritten.

Comment: If think there might be a way where you can load local file contents into an anonymouse JavaScript bytestream and upload this to a server without the filename from the clients computer. But I doubt you really need/want this.

Comment: When you upload a file to PHP, it stores the file in a random location with a random name to do exactly this: not produce dupliates. When the file finished uploading, you can move the file to your own path and name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rename function of PHP  to rename your files:
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rename.php

If you want to rename multiple files, you can create a function that will search through the file folder (using for, while etc) and rename 1 by 1 using some parameter.

To store the file path, you can simply use a mysqli query to store the file path to your database.